# Using the 'current()' function in a pattern to apply custom templates to Nodes

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I am implementing a system in with a user can generate a document on a collection of *Items*. An item contains a *Name* and a *ItemTypeId*. A user can select what template to apply to what item of a certain type. This is stored in a *composition*-object which contains a mapping of itemTypeId's to TemplateId's.

So the XML-data used to generate the document looks like this:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <composition>
    <ItemType>
      <ItemTypeId>IT1</ItemTypeId>
      <TemplateId>T1</TemplateId>
    </ItemType>
    <ItemType>
      <ItemTypeId>IT2</ItemTypeId>
      <TemplateId>T3</TemplateId>
    </ItemType>
    <ItemType>
      <ItemTypeId>IT3</ItemTypeId>
      <TemplateId>T2</TemplateId>
    </ItemType>
    <ItemType>
      <ItemTypeId>IT4</ItemTypeId>
      <TemplateId>T1</TemplateId>
    </ItemType>
  </composition>
  <items>
    <item>
      <ItemTypeId>IT1</ItemTypeId>
      <Name>A</Name>
    </item>
    <item>
      <ItemTypeId>IT2</ItemTypeId>
      <Name>B</Name>
    </item>
    <item>
      <ItemTypeId>IT3</ItemTypeId>
      <Name>C</Name>
    </item>
    <item>
      <ItemTypeId>IT2</ItemTypeId>
      <Name>D</Name>
    </item>
  </items>
</data>
```

To generate the document I want to use an XSLT containing 4 templates.

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Document</h2>
<xsl:for-each select="/data/items/item">
<xsl:variable name="itemTypeId" select="current()/ItemTypeId" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="current()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[/data/composition/ItemType[ItemTypeId = current()/ItemTypeId]/TemplateId='T1']">
 <h1>T1</h1>
 Item <xsl:value-of select="current()/Name"/> 
 with type <xsl:value-of select="current()/ItemTypeId"/><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[/data/composition/ItemType[ItemTypeId = current()/ItemTypeId]/TemplateId='T2']">
 <h1>T2</h1>
 Item <xsl:value-of select="current()/Name"/> 
 with type <xsl:value-of select="current()/ItemTypeId"/><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[/data/composition/ItemType[ItemTypeId = current()/ItemTypeId]/TemplateId='T3']">
 <h1>T3</h1>
 Item <xsl:value-of select="current()/Name"/> 
 with type <xsl:value-of select="current()/ItemTypeId"/><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[/data/composition/ItemType[ItemTypeId = current()/ItemTypeId]/TemplateId='T4']">
 <h1>T4</h1>
 Item <xsl:value-of select="current()/Name"/> 
 with type <xsl:value-of select="current()/ItemTypeId"/><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
</xsl:template>
```

I use the current() function in the match pattern to look in the composition and see if the template needs to be applied or not. This works perfectly in online XSLT editor of [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) and generates the following document:

**Output (On W3Schools xslt editor):**

> ### Document
>
> ## T1
>
> Item A with type
>   IT1
>
> ## T3
>
> Item B with type IT2
>
> ## T2
>
> Item C
>   with type IT3
>
> ## T3
>
> Item D with type IT2

However, when I try to implement this in a .Net application I get the following error:

> The 'current()' function cannot be used in a pattern.

It seems to me that .NET does not allow the use of *current()* in match patterns. Does anybody know a way around this problem? Or can somebody point out a  flaw in my logic?

**Edit**
I apply the xslt using the standard .NET methods in *System.Xml.Xsl* like so:

```
  XElement data = XElement.Parse("xml is entered here");
  XElement stylesheet = XElement.Parse("xslt is entered here");
  XslCompiledTransform compiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
  compiledTransform.Load(stylesheet.CreateReader());
  // Create an xml writer to write to the result stream.
  using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(result, compiledTransform.OutputSettings))
  {
      // Apply the transformation.
      compiledTransform.Transform(data.CreateReader(), null, writer);
  }
  // Return the result.
  return result;
```

Comment: I think most uses of current() are superfluous, i.e. you could simply write `<xsl:variable name="itemTypeId" select="ItemTypeId" />` ? You usually would wrap plain text inside `<xsl:text>` / `</xsl:text>` tags to prevent all the whitespace dripping in. At places where you only have `"current()"` you could try `"."` - But I see this does not answer the question about the template matches.

Comment: Please show us the .NET code so that we know which class or API exactly you use. And are you willing to use a different XSLT processor like Saxon or XmlPrime if you currently used one does give that error?

Comment: Unfortunatyle this does not solve my problem. I agree with you that in most cases you could use `<xsl:variable name="itemTypeId" select="ItemTypeId" /> `, however I this case that would mean I need to reference a variable in the _match_ attritubute of _template_ even though it is defined outside of the scope of this template. It is not an option to define this in global scope since XSLT does not allow for it value to change, and it needs to change  for every _item_.

Comment: I editted the post to contain information about which API I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="data/composition/ItemType" use="ItemTypeId"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Document</h2>

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/items/item"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[key('ref', ItemTypeId)/TemplateId='T1']">
        <h1>T1</h1>
        Item <xsl:value-of select="current()/Name"/> 
        with type <xsl:value-of select="current()/ItemTypeId"/><br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[key('ref', ItemTypeId)/TemplateId='T2']">
        <h1>T2</h1>
        Item <xsl:value-of select="current()/Name"/> 
        with type <xsl:value-of select="current()/ItemTypeId"/><br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[key('ref', ItemTypeId)/TemplateId='T3']">
        <h1>T3</h1>
        Item <xsl:value-of select="current()/Name"/> 
        with type <xsl:value-of select="current()/ItemTypeId"/><br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[key('ref', ItemTypeId)/TemplateId='T4']">
        <h1>T4</h1>
        Item <xsl:value-of select="current()/Name"/> 
        with type <xsl:value-of select="current()/ItemTypeId"/><br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That somehow looks as if the four templates are better simplified to a single template

```
    <xsl:template match="item[key('ref', ItemTypeId)]">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="key('ref', ItemTypeId)/TemplateId"/></h1>
        Item <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> 
        with type <xsl:value-of select="ItemTypeId"/><br/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Or you need to switch to an XSLT 2.0 processor like [Saxon 9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/) or XmlPrime where the use of `current()` in a pattern is supported.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I am by no means an expect and was not aware I could use a key object. Thank you! BTW: I cannot change to one template since the whole point of my system is to dynamically add the templates and allow for them to have a completely different content.